# Javascript runs late and has a lag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to run a slideshow on my website using JavaScript.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="image_slider">
    <img class="active" src="images/slider/slider1.jpg" alt="My image" />
    <img src="images/slider/slider1.jpg" alt="My image" />  
    <img src="images/slider/slider2.jpg" alt="My image" />  
    <img src="images/slider/slider3.jpg" alt="My image" />
    <img src="images/slider/slider4.jpg" alt="My image" />
    <img src="images/slider/slider5.jpg" alt="My image" />      
</div>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
function cycleImages(){
    var $active = $('#image_slider .active');
    var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : $('#image_slider img:first');
    $next.css('z-index',2); //move the next image up the pile
    $active.fadeOut(1000,function(){ //fade out the top image
        $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active'); //reset the z-index and unhide the image
        $next.css('z-index',3).addClass('active'); //make the next image the top one
   });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    // run every 3s
    setInterval('cycleImages()', 3000);
})
```

The code runs well but with a glitch.

When the page loads, the first image fades off to the second image after a long time. This strange behaviour is seen again when the loop is repeated.

Why is there this lag with the first image?

Comment: Is it a typo that you have `slider1.jpg` two times in your code?

Comment: Create a demo that replicates problem if it isn't a typo or delete post if it is. Learn how to use `console.log()` to help uncover problems in your code

Comment: Is it possible that your page is just slow to load then when dom content finally fires, your script is run three seconds later hence what seems like a long time. Might want to call cycleImages() and then call setInterval().

Comment: maybe try to downsize your images or make thumbnails... onclick take the bigger ones